# how to remove escape slash from string in android

Tags: java, android, regex, string, removeall

I have tried all possible solution but couldn't find any answers.

I have following string.

```
"{\"property_type\":[\"residential\"],\"status\":[\"active\"],\"category\":[\"sale\"],\"page_size\":8,\"cur_page\":1}"
```

This is response I am getting from json.

Please help me with this concern.

Comment: do you want to remove the slashes in the android itself or passing value to server and remove slashes using any other language like i.e) Php

Comment: @karthick: I got this response from branch , now I want to send this request to my server , but this escape slash is occurred here , I tried .replaceAll("\\",") and .replaceAll(""\","") , but no luck.

Comment: @karthick: then how you solve ? please let me know.

Comment: Could you please try with follwoing
replaceAll("\\\\", "") or replaceAll("\\\\/", "/").

Comment: i used php to decode the data

Comment: @ChayanChowdhury: hey it work for me please write answer.

Comment: Simply use in android  receivedString.replaceAll("\"", "\"");

Comment: @mohsin great . you can accept my answer then.

Comment: It seems like you are wanting to decode json! Smell of XY problem

Comment: @Danh: yes , this response from branchio from server side it is java script.

Comment: @MohsinKhan Then why don't you use those available JSON library instead?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may try this if you want to remove escape slash from android ....

```
String receivedString = "{\"property_type\":[\"residential\"],\"status\":[\"active\"],\"category\":[\"sale\"],\"page_size\":8,\"cur_page\":1}";

    String changedString = receivedString.replaceAll("\"", "\"");
    Log.d("your_tag", changedString);
```

Output will be like below :

```
{"property_type":["residential"],"status":["active"],"category":["sale"],"page_size":8,"cur_page":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.replaceAll("\\/","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$postdata = stripslashes("[".$_POST["data"]."]");
$data = json_decode($postdata,true);
try{
if(is_array($data)){
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $line1 = $row['line1'];
        $line2 = $row['line2'];
        $line3 = $row['line3'];
        $line4 = $row['line4'];
    }
}
}catch(Exception $e){

}
```

here i am passing the data from my android app to my server and decode the values using the above code successfully

hope it helps to you...

Comment: I got solution from above comment i used  bundle_data.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Comment: oh ok thats great
if you want to decode the data on server side use my code all the best....

Answer (score -2):

yesss finally this works for me :

```
//delete backslashes ( \ ) :
            data = data.replaceAll("[\\\\]{1}[\"]{1}","\"");
//delete first and last double quotation ( " ) :
            data = data.substring(data.indexOf("{"),data.lastIndexOf("}")+1);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
```